# Causality Theory of Space-Time.

Tags: reference-request, physics, general-relativity, reference-works

I'm looking for some books about causality theory in physics from mathematical point of view. I'm already using *Global Lorentzian Geometry* by John Beem and *Semi-riemannian Geometry* by Barret O'Neill. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hawking & Ellis (1973) is a classic, see chapter 6, "Causal structure". There's also Penrose (1972) on "differential topology" but much is about causality.